# How do I save two models with has_many through on the same form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I've had this question about ruby on rails some time ago, and managed to solve it in some way:

The solution I've found is use nesting forms with the join model(fields_for), saving the third model within an external form and inserting its ID with ajax.
The problem is that the nested form is too big to nest inside Order form(main form).

I'm not satisfied with this solution, so here it is:

Let's say I have three models:

- Order
- Order-List (has_many through model)
- List

So, the Order contains different Lists, and each List has Items (With other has_many relationships between).

In an example, know that I can save the information about the has_many through model on the same form, but how do I save an Order AND a new List(on the same form)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked nesting forms with accept_nested_attributes_for on the model and "field_for :relationship" on the form? you should at least show the way you got working before that you are not satisfied though.

Comment: The solution I've found is use nesting forms with the join model, saving the third model within an external form and inserting its ID with ajax.
Can I use it directly with the third model (List, on the example) and expect that the information to be automatically stored in the join model?